# Fluent validation and Must custom validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a class and my validation looks like this:

```
    public ValidationResult Validate(CustomerType customerType)
    {
        CustomerType Validator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator();
        validator.RuleFor(x => x.Number).Must(BeUniqueNumber);

        return validator.Validate(customerType);
    }

    public bool BeUniqueNumber(int number)
    {
        //var result = repository.Get(x => x.Number == customerType.Number)
        //                       .Where(x => x.Id != customerType.Id)
        //                       .FirstOrDefault();

        //return result == null;
        return true;
    }
```

The CustomerTypeValidator is a basic validator class that validates string properties.

I also add a new rule to check if the number is unique in the db. I do it in this class because there's a reference to the repository. The validator class has no such reference.

The problem here is that the BeUniqueNumber method should have a CustomerType parameter. However when I do this, I get an error on the RuleFor line above because 'Must' needs an int as a parameter.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
public ValidationResult Validate(CustomerType customerType)
{
    CustomerTypeValidator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator();
    validator.RuleFor(x => x).Must(HaveUniqueNumber);

    return validator.Validate(customerType);
}

public bool HaveUniqueNumber(CustomerType customerType)
{
    var result = repository.Get(x => x.Number == customerType.Number)
        .Where(x => x.Id != customerType.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return result == null;
    //return true;
}
```

You should also be able to do this:

```
public ValidationResult Validate(CustomerType customerType)
{
    CustomerTypeValidator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator();
    validator.RuleFor(x => x.Number).Must(BeUniqueNumber);

    return validator.Validate(customerType);
}

public bool BeUniqueNumber(CustomerType customerType, int number)
{
    var result = repository.Get(x => x.Number == number)
        .Where(x => x.Id != customerType.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return result == null;
    //return true;
}
```

> "I also add a new rule to check if the number is unique in the db. I do
>   it in this class because there's a reference to the repository."

Well, why can't you give your validator a reference to the repository too?

```
CustomerTypeValidator validator = new CustomerTypeValidator(repository);
```

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't work because 'Must' needs <T, TProperty>

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono that's odd, are you sure? I just tried something very similar, and the Predicate method only needs a `T`, not a `TProperty`. Are you sure you are doing `x => `x, and not `x => x.Number`? I have also updated my answer with another alternative.

Comment: I've already tried both ways and they won't work. I'd rather not pass the repository around if there's a solution without doing so.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono what version of fluent validation are you using? Are you getting a compiler / build error? If so, what is the exact error? Like I said, the above code works when I build it (against FluentValidation 5.0.0.1). Could you provide the source for your CustomerType and CustomerTypeValidator in the OP?

Comment: My bad. Your answer with the first example works fine. I had BeUniqueNumber() when I re-edited the code.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono that's what I was expecting. You can also keep the `BeUniqueNumber` method name and use the second option, it should achieve the same result.